# How to set just a field name via itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields?

Tags: c#, itext

I want to set just a field name leaving the value empty in my C# code so I am wondering is there any other way to do that except :

```
stamper.AcroFields.SetField("license", "");
```

Is that possible with setFieldProperty(String field, String name, Object value, int[] inst) method in AcroFieds class? What it is for?

Please help,

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear. Let me give you three answers in the hope that one of my answers matches your question.

**You want to add a field to an existing document:**

This isn't done with the `SetField()` method (`AcroFields`) but with the `AddAnnotation()` method (`PdfStamper`). You create a `PdfFormField` instance (e.g. with the help of the `TextField` class) and you add it to a specific page.

```
stamper.AddAnnotation(field, pagenumber);
```

**You want to rename an existing field**

This isn't done with the `SetField()` method, but with the `RenameField()` method. See [iTextSharp RenameField bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344750/itextsharp-renamefield-bug) for more info.

**You want to change properties in an existing field**

There are two methods to change properties: one to change a flag, another one to change an actual property.

Form field flags can be:

- READ_ONLY
- REQUIRED
- MULTILINE
- DO_NOT_SCROLL
- PASSWORD
- FILE_SELECTION
- PASSWORD
- DO_NOT_SPELL_CHECK
- EDIT
- MULTISELECT
- COMB

There are also annotation flags, for instance to change the visibility: only visible on screen, only visible when printed, always visible, never visible.

The actual properties are:

- textfont
- textcolor
- textsize
- bgcolor
- bordercolor

This info is taken from [chapter 8 of my book](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=8).

Comment: Thanks man, actually I was looking for RenameField() method. It works, thanks again for extensive hint and bringing me back on track.