# Get value of radiobutton group

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I use itextsharp lib in my asp.net MVC project and have few radiobutton groups in pdf file. This file was created in Adobe Acrobat software as editable form.
When I display name and type ([Get specific types from AcroField](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-get-specific-types-acrofields-pushbuttonfield-radiocheckfield-etc)) of all editable fields, unfortunately get only type of radiobutton group as "RADIOBUTTON", but subradiobutton doesn't show.

How Can I display it?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "subradiobutton" type. Please check ISO-32000-1 if you don't believe me.

The hierarchy of the fields is established through the names of the fields. See my answer to the question [iTextSharp RenameField bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344750/itextsharp-renamefield-bug) The dots in the field names refer to a hierarchy.

For instance: if you have a field named `person`; this field can have children such as

- `name`, and
- `address`.

The fully qualified names of these child fields would then be:

- `person.name`, and
- `person.address`.

Address can in turn have child fields, such as:

- `street`,
- `city`, and
- `country`.

This results in fully qualified names such as:

- `person.address.street`,
- `person.address.city`, and
- `person.address.country`.

If you are looking for "subradiobuttons", you should look at the fully qualified names of the fields, and examine how many dots (`.`) they have.

You are probably also confused about the difference between a radio field and a radio button. A radio field is a field that has a specific name, e.g. `language`. The value of that `language` can be chosen by clicking one of many radio buttons. These buttons are widget annotations with two appearance states (selected and not-selected). If you want to know the possible values of a radio field, you need to get those appearance states.

You've already seen the method that is needed to do this in [How to get specific types from AcroFields? Like PushButtonField, RadioCheckField, etc](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-get-specific-types-acrofields-pushbuttonfield-radiocheckfield-etc):

```
form.GetAppearanceStates("language");
```